# Set of points visited by a Markov chain issued from a point x

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I am looking for examples of Markov chains for each of the following conditions:

- The set of points visited by the chain issued from a point x is not a.s. constant.
- The set of points visited by the chain issued from a point x is a.s. constant, the order of the first three points visited is not deterministic, and x is not recurrent.

There are probably easy examples, but I just can't think of any, so I'd be grateful for some help.

Comment: First point: almost any transient chain fits. Second point: sure this is what you mean?

Comment: @Did: Thanks! About the second point: it's from an exercise, so I don't know if there is maybe something wrong with the formulation of the problem...

Comment: @caedmon I'm curious exactly how to interpret what is being asked. When the exercise reads: "The set of points visited by the chain is a.s. constant" .. am I to interpret this as: "There exists a finite collection $x_1, ..., x_n$ of points such that for every $t= 0, 1, 2, ...$, $P(X_t \in \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}) = 1$" and similarly for the "not a.s. constant"

Comment: @Tom Yes, I mean, that's how I understand it.